# A simple Script to extracting a zip file

Tags: python, unzip, zip, xbmc, kodi

Good Evening all,

I think I'm not understanding the zipfile structure properly heres the code

```
import xbmc
import zipfile

targetzip = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.tester/test.zip')
extractto = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.tester/')

zip = ZipFile(targetzip)
zip.extractall(extractto)
```

Any Ideas why Its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it this way

```
import zipfile

fh = open(targetzip, 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
for name in z.namelist():
    z.extract(name, extractto)
fh.close()
```

Comment: With a few adjustments this was perfect Cheers Aleksander Monk

Comment: You can accept my answer if it was really helpful for you :) @SimonJeal

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(targetzip) as zf:
    zf.extractall(extractto)
```